# Should I reply to a company post-interview that I'll be happy to do the internship even if it is unpaid?

Tags: salary, internship

I had an interview last week for a 10-week internship. Went OK, just needs clearance from his boss. Internship was paid as much as the longer internships, around 60% of an average low monthly salary in the country.

Today I get the advice from a person who does a fair bit of business that I should call them up again and offer to do it for free. Since the internship is so short, they are probably actually going to run a financial loss on me considering medical insurance and other costs. Offering to do it for free will improve my chances and eliminate hesitation.

*Considerations:*

- I have the financial resources to work for free. I'm going to sleep at my parents and use their car.
- The company is financially healthy. Business is growing and relative to the greater picture it's a fairly unsubstantial amount of money.
- Originally, I was advised that I should not offer to do it for free, since I come across as (perhaps) desperate or too well-off to care. Then again, they brought up the compensation topic in the interview themselves.

Field: Engineering, Central Europe.

Comment: If you offer to work unpaid, you'll probably be considered _only_ for the unpaid position. Wait for them to answer before changing the terms.

Answer (score 4):

I'd wait for them to come back to you. If you don't get any response in a while, you can send an email asking if they have made a decision or if there are any updates. Don't let them know you'd work for free, because if they were considering hiring you and paying you, they'll end up hiring you for free instead. If they weren't going to hire you, it's very unlikely doing it for free would change their minds.

Answer (score 3):

Offering to do it for free does make you look desperate, and you should never value yourself as zero. I wouldn't do anything until they get back to you.